# Combinatorics - Painting the Unit Squares of a 3x3 Square

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I need some help with the exercise I was assigned in math class. We were given a 3x3 square made of unit squares, and we wanted to paint all the squares. We had 3 sets of paint, red, blue, and green. Each paint was distinct from each other, but two unit squares with the same color were the same. Additionally, there's only enough paint of each color to color 3 unit squares, and all the paint has to be used. The goal of the exercise was to find the total amount of distinct possible ways such that no two unit squares that share an edge (that is to say they are next to each other vertically or horizontally, having same color across a diagonal is fine).

I've started by trying to take a look at each possible arrangement of the bottom 3 unit squares, but I can't seem to find a pattern between it. Is there a better way than continuing by brute force? Any ideas on how I should proceed from here?

Comment: Not sure there is an easier way than just enumerating the possible arrangements.  There are not that many.  This will work for 3x3 but not for N>>1.

Comment: Ok, is there a way to at least calculate all possibilities, without restrictions? That way I can make sure I have achieved the total.

Comment: If you add the condition where each color can show up in each row exactly once, then this becomes counting derangement. But to count all patterns you might really have to just brute force it.

Comment: I just asked for some hints and was given a few answer choices. The largest of those were 36 possibilities. The others were the numbers incrementing downwards by 6. So 30, 24, 18, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $3$ colours for the central square. For each such case we have:-

The four  squares adjacent to the central square either consist of

A. $3$ squares of the same colour - $8$ possibilities.

B. $2$ squares of each colour opposite each other- $2$ possibilities.

C. $2$ squares of each colour not opposite each other- $4$ possibilities.

The corner squares can then be chosen in the following number of ways

A. $1$

B. $0$

C. $1$

**Total number of arrangements is $3\times (8+4)=36$**

N.B. This number will be smaller if we count arrangements which are the same under rotation as actually being the same.

Comment: The number seems to be a bit large, as the largest choice I had was $36$ possibilities. Reading over it, it seems you may have missed the condition where there's at most 3 unit squares of each color. But I think rotation is still distinct.

Comment: Yes - I did miss that extra condition. Thanks - I've now taken it into account.

Answer (score 1):

** NOT A SOLUTION **

**Hint:** Consider diagonals.  There are 3 classes

3 different values

2 different values

1 value

Easier to enumerate them all in each class and by definition they are mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive.

For example for $\text{diag}(1,2,3)$ this is the only solution $\{132,321,213\}$

For $\text{diag}(1,1,1)$ there are two.