# Need help on counting problem that involves placing 3 sets of indistinguishable cupcakes on a 3x3 board.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

This is the question I'm referring to from the title
"Martha and Janet are making cupcakes for a party. They have a 3x3 board to arrange them on and they have 3 indistinguishable blue cupcakes, 3 indistinguishable red cupcakes, and 3 indistinguishable orange cupcakes. In how many ways can they arrange these cupcakes such that no two cupcakes of the same color are adjacent horizontally or vertically."

I was able to get the answer by just writing it out by hand and counting up the total number of arrangements, but wanted to know if there was any shortcut that would get the answer way faster.

Comment: Already asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012688/combinatorics-painting-the-unit-squares-of-a-3x3-square

Comment: I've posted an answer at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012688/combinatorics-painting-the-unit-squares-of-a-3x3-square

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinatorics - Painting the Unit Squares of a 3x3 Square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4012688/combinatorics-painting-the-unit-squares-of-a-3x3-square)